# What is the difference between var num=30 and var num=new Number(30) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, syntax

It seems like there are so many different ways to do the same things in JavaScript.  Is there any difference in using the "new" keyword in JavaScript for numbers and just entering a number?  I see no difference between:

```
var num = 30;

var num = new Number(30);
```

It's the same with strings (and arrays):

```
var str = "hello";

var str = new String("hello");
```

Why would someone use one method over the other?  They seem the same to me, and it's just more typing anyway.

Comment: I almost always use the first (primitive version).

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number `The primary uses for the Number object are: 1) If the argument cannot be converted into a number, it returns NaN. 2) In a non-constructor context (i.e., without the new operator), Number can be used to perform a type conversion.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first creates a primitive. The other an object.

In theory there is a difference but in practice none. The JavaScript engine automagicly *boxes* a primitive to an object when it needs to be an object.

```
var myPrimitiveNumber = 42;
// calling .toFixed will 'box' the primitive into a number object,
// run the method and then 'unbox' it back to a primitive
console.log( myPrimitiveNumber.toFixed(2) );
```

The only usage I've found is if you want to return a primitive from a constructor function.

```
function Foo() {
    return 42;
}

var foo = new Foo();
console.log(foo); // foo is instance of Foo

function Bar() {
    return new Number(42);
}

var bar = new Bar();
console.log(bar); // bar is instance of Number
```

Comment: Note that `new Number(42) ==  new Number(42)` is false