# difference between a = 1 and a = new Number()

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between var a and var a = new Number() and later assigning the value of a to 1

When consoled I see one as undefined and one has Number{}. What would be the most notable differences to be known as implementation progresses.

Comment: A case of primitive vs object. Don't use `new Number`.

Comment: If you later assign it a new value then it makes absolutely no difference what you use to initialize it.

Comment: Not a dupe but might answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369220/why-should-you-not-use-number-as-a-constructor

Comment: The first creates a primitive. The other an object.
For correct answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27083391/what-is-the-difference-between-var-num-30-and-var-num-new-number30-in-javascri

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that you shouldn't use [`new Number()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number).
`new Number` creates an object, which will be overridden the moment you assign some other value to it. The other just creates a primitive.

The only reason you'd use `Number` is to parse strings to numeric values:

```
var a = Number("1e20"),
    b = Number("1.6");
```

(Keep in mind there's `parseInt` and `parseFloat` as well.)

Or to access a couple of constants:

```
var biggestNum = Number.MAX_VALUE;
var smallestNum = Number.MIN_VALUE;
var infiniteNum = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
var negInfiniteNum = Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
var notANum = Number.NaN;
```

Don't use `Number` as a declaration like that. There's really no point in doing so.

If you're only as assigning numeric values to variables, without any kind of parsing, just assign them:

```
var a = 5,
    b = 5234;
```

Answer (score -2):

Number() allows you to parse strings or other variable types, it is not meant as declaration, since variables don't have types in javascript.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_number.asp

Comment: Referencing w3schools is generally frowned upon on Stack Overflow. Try to use [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) instead.